# How do you properly add a C# stand alone script as a step in Octopus Deploy?

Tags: c#, octopus-deploy

So, I'm looking into adding a C# [stand alone script](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-examples/custom-scripts/standalone-scripts) as part of a Step in a deployment process, but am having a **really** hard time finding a reference that show how to properly "format" the script for use by Octopus.

One thing I did find was that all references need to be explicit. So for instance, if the script makes use of `HttpClient` to make a GET request, you can't rely on a `using` statements to shorten the reference, but instead have to use the "fully qualified namespace".

So basically instead of being able to do this:
`HttpClient client = new HttpClient();`

You have to do it like this:
`System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.HttpClient()`

Okay, so I've modified my script to make explicit reference to any class or method within its given namespace.

Now, what happens if I have a custom class? How do I handle that? I'll illustrate what I mean with an example. Say I have the following:

```
using System;

namespace MyOctoScript
{
      class Person
      {
             public string name { get; set; }
      }

     class Script
     {
          static System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
          static System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
          public const string endpoint = "some_valid_endpoint";

           static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string [] args)
           {
                 MyOctoScript.Person person = null;

                // Use Http Client to fetch JSON from a given endpoint
                System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);

               // Parse JSON from response
               string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

              // Store object in variable of type Person
              person = serializer.Deserialize<MyOctoScript.Person>(jsonString);
           }
     }
}
```

Now, this script works as a console application. I want to ensure it works once I add it as a C# script that is part of a Step.

What changes (if any) do I need to make to the code above to achieve this?

Thanks to anyone in advance!

Comment: same issues, cannot figure out how to not get "Step templates that do not include a script body are currently not supported" when importing a script from a package as a step template. Tried using the export from a work custom template, normal function, inline code and nothing works.

Comment: @jsdev17 I am also looking for a similar issue . Still couldn't find any guidance on the right direction. Were you able to rectify this issue if so would be great if you can share this

Answer (score 1):

The Docs say Octopus supports C# via ScriptCS

- https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-examples/custom-scripts#supported-script-types
- https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs

So I'd assume (untested) you'd need to flatten it to something like this:

```
using System;

class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

static System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
static System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
public const string endpoint = "some_valid_endpoint";

Person person = null;

// Use Http Client to fetch JSON from a given endpoint
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);

// Parse JSON from response
string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// Store object in variable of type Person
person = serializer.Deserialize<Person>(jsonString);
```

tbh, I'm not sure how ScripCS handles Async, so there's some work to do to figure that out.

ScriptCS can be used to run standalone scripts or as a REPL, so you can test it locally.